# Authentication for BandPage API

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth

I am trying to access the BandPage API using this script which I found on Github. I have very little experience with PHP so can't really figure out what is wrong with this. This is the script:

```
<?php

function bandpageToken($client_id,$shared_secret) {

        if($_COOKIE['bp_access_token']) {

                $access_token = $_COOKIE['bp_access_token'];

        } else {

                //set POST variables
                $url = 'https://api-read.bandpage.com/token';
                $fields = array(
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'grant_type' => "client_credentials"
                );

                //open connection
                $ch = curl_init();

                //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id . ':' . $shared_secret);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                //execute post
                $result = curl_exec($ch);

                $obj = json_decode($result);
                
                setcookie("bp_access_token", $obj->access_token, time()+$obj->expires_in-10);
                $access_token = $obj->access_token;

                //close connection
                curl_close($ch);

        }

        return $access_token;

}

$app_id = 'MyIdIsHere';
$client_id = 'clientIdIsHere';
$shared_secret = 'sharedSecerecIsHere';
$access_token = bandpageToken($client_id,$shared_secret);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Bandpage Connect</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>;(function(){var e="sdk-js.bandpage.com",t="/embedscript/connect";window._rm_lightningjs||function(e){function n(n,r){var i="1";return r&&(r+=(/\?/.test(r)?"&":"?")+"lv="+i),e[n]||function(){var i=window,s=document,o=n,u=s.location.protocol,a="load",f=0;(function(){function l(){n.P(a),n.w=1,e[o]("_load")}e[o]=function(){function a(){return a.id=s,e[o].apply(a,arguments)}var t=arguments,r=this,s=++f,u=r&&r!=i?r.id||0:0;return(n.s=n.s||[]).push([s,u,t]),a.then=function(e,t,r){var i=n.fh[s]=n.fh[s]||[],o=n.eh[s]=n.eh[s]||[],u=n.ph[s]=n.ph[s]||[];return e&&i.push(e),t&&o.push(t),r&&u.push(r),a},a};var n=e[o]._={};n.fh={},n.eh={},n.ph={},n.l=r?r.replace(/^\/\//,(u=="https:"?u:"http:")+"//"):r,n.p={0:+(new Date)},n.P=function(e){n.p[e]=new Date-n.p[0]},n.w&&l(),i.addEventListener?i.addEventListener(a,l,!1):i.attachEvent("on"+a,l),n.l&&function(){function e(){return["<",r,' onload="var d=',p,";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].",u,"(d.",a,"('script')).",f,"='",n.l,"'\">"].join("")}var r="body",i=s[r];if(!i)return setTimeout(arguments.callee,100);n.P(1);var u="appendChild",a="createElement",f="src",l=s[a]("div"),c=l[u](s[a]("div")),h=s[a]("iframe"),p="document",d="domain",v,m="contentWindow";l.style.display="none",i.insertBefore(l,i.firstChild).id=t+"-"+o,h.frameBorder="0",h.id=t+"-frame-"+o,/MSIE[ ]+6/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(h[f]="javascript:false"),h.allowTransparency="true",c[u](h);try{h[m][p].open()}catch(g){n[d]=s[d],v="javascript:var d="+p+".open();d.domain='"+s.domain+"';",h[f]=v+"void(0);"}try{var y=h[m][p];y.write(e()),y.close()}catch(b){h[f]=v+'d.write("'+e().replace(/"/g,String.fromCharCode(92)+'"')+'");d.close();'}n.P(2)}()})()}(),e[n].lv=i,e[n]}var t="_rm_lightningjs",r=window[t]=n(t);r.require=n,r.modules=e}({}),function(n){if(n.bandpage)return;var r=_rm_lightningjs.require("$rm","//"+e+t),i=function(){},s=function(t){t.done||(t.done=i),t.fail||(t.fail=i);var n=r("load",t);n.then(t.done,t.fail);var s={done:function(e){return n.then(e,i),s},fail:function(e){return n.then(i,e),s}};return s},o=null;n.bandpage={load:s,ready:function(e){o.then(e,i)}},o=r("bootstrap",n.bandpage,window)}(window)})(this);</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            bandpage.load({
                "done" : function() {
                     var connection = bandpage.sdk.connect({
                          appId : "<?=$app_id?>",
                          access_token : "<?=$access_token?>",
                          container : $('.btn-container').get(0),
                          allow_reconnect : false
                    });
                                connection.on("bpconnect.complete", function(bands){
                                        console.log("User has authed bands!");
                                        console.log(bands);
                                });
                                connection.on("bpconnect.cancel", function(){
                                        console.log("User clicked the cancel button and connect window is closed");
                                });
                },
                "fail" : function() {
                    console.log("Failed to initialize sdk");
                }
            });            
    </script>
    <style>
            .btn-container {
                    top: 50%;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 50%;
                    margin: -22px 0 0 -117px;
            }            
    </style>
    </head>
        <body>
                <div class='btn-container'></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

and the error seems to be with the `bp_access_token`, errors below.

> Notice: Undefined index: bp_access_token in C:\wamp\www\Testing\index.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Testing\index.php on line 33
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Testing\index.php on line 34

Do I need to declare `bp_access_token` somewhere or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script hasn't been written very well. On line 5, an array access is made in the cookies array without first checking it exists. The author may have `display_errors` turned off, but not everyone does.

This:

```
if($_COOKIE['bp_access_token']) {
```

would be better expressed as:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['bp_access_token']) && $_COOKIE['bp_access_token']) {
```

That will fix your first notice. As for the other two, you are making object accesses on null values in these lines:

```
setcookie("bp_access_token", $obj->access_token, time()+$obj->expires_in-10);
$access_token = $obj->access_token;
```

My guess would be that your authentication to BandPage has failed, and you don't have a valid response object to work with. Double-check the values of these in the script, which must be supplied by you:

- $app_id
- $client_id
- $shared_secret

You can probably get these from a control panel somewhere in your BandPage account screen.

Answer (score 0):

add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` 
just after `<?php` tag.

if your script is working perfectly but warning/notices are showing, you can add
`error_reporting(0);`

keep in mind to comment out this line as soon as you face some problem with this script next time.

Comment: I added the line above and no longer get errors, but now i just have a blank page returned.